# Retroactive automatic editing of question punctuation affecting correctness

Tags: discussion, titles

The [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8323/does-stirlings-formula-give-the-correct-number-of-digits-of-n) formerly titled "Does Stirling's formula give the correct number of digits of n!?" is now titled "Does Stirling's formula give the correct number of digits of n?".  This was not due to an edit, and is incorrect.  I speculated that this might be the result of a retroactive automatic systemwide editing of punctuation.

Searching meta.SO, I found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99871/can-should-we-get-rid-of-multiple-punctuation-marks/100104#100104) that seems to show that this was done intentionally.  I can understand the motivation to clean up questions with bad punctuation, but I am concerned that it may remove certain instances of correct notation appearing in titles.  There are plenty of ways to work around it in the example given above (e.g. by writing `...n factorial?` or `...$n!$?`).  But I wonder if it is worthwhile enough that we should have to work around it, and I wonder if there have been/will be other instances of valid mathematical notation conflicting with automatic punctuation editing that is not as easy to work around, or other cases of old posts like the one above that may confuse readers during the potentially long interval before they are corrected.

I am not making this a feature request, because I would like to hear what others think.  I am undecided on whether the benefits outweigh the costs.  Admittedly, I may have (luckily) happened upon the only instance of the changes making a title incorrect, but I have no way of knowing.  Please share your thoughts if you would like to.

Comment: well, that question could do with a thorough editing anyway, could it not?

Comment: @Jeff: That's not the point, is it now? The point is that automated editing can be harmful.

Comment: @Jeff: Yeah, the body could use some work, but that is another story.  KennyTM did his best, but the OP removed the LaTeX for some reason.

Comment: What is especially... inconvenient is that automatic editing leaves no traces in revision history, so one can't even understand what happened...

Comment: (Posted last comment as [suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101678/automatic-edits-revision-history) on Meta.SO.)

Comment: Moreover this "feature" makes incorrect many other mathematical questions, e.g. any terminal use of ellipses is deleted, and ellipses occur in many mathematical objects (power series, sequences, ...). So unless they are in TeX they will be *silently deleted*.

Comment: Perhaps this deserves posting where other stackexchangers will see it.

Comment: To paraphrase what Theo commented in another post: "I was expecting humans to be editing my posts, not some mindless scripts..."

Comment: ...and most galling is that these auto-edits are untraceable. If the SE overlords will be saddling us with their scripts, it would be nice if they, you know, **left a trail for debugging purposes**? If (smarter) humans' edits are always logged, why should dumb scripts be exempt?

Comment: @J.M.: You probably noticed, but just in case: That request has been posted by Grigory M in [another thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101678/automatic-edits-revision-history) (also linked 5 comments up).

Comment: I did @Jonas, but still, thanks. :)

Comment: @J.M. \phantom, hmm? Clever. What is phantom actually for?

Comment: @mix: [This](http://books.google.com.ph/books?id=PNTyn-ueEbYC&pg=PA191) might illuminate `\phantom{}` a bit... :)

Comment: Cue the old joke: "Professor Smith, I've finished typing your paper.  By the way, I noticed several places where you misspelled 'if' with an extra 'f', so I corrected them."

Answer (score 34):

To expand on Noah Snyder's answer: If you agree that no automated editing of old questions or answers should be done in the future without being first proposed and agreed upon on *this meta*, please vote this answer up. If you disagree, please vote this answer down.

Comment: I'd add comments to that.

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with this particular idea, simply because of the scale of such a requirement. If we catered to every site that had an opposition to a global feature here and there, and had to get through each one of them, it'd immensely slow the process of implementing global features considering there are 60 sites currently and quite more expected. I certainly can understand the discomfort of what happened here, and something could be done to mitigate this, but I can't say I find that this solution is truly sustainable.

Comment: @Grace If you desire to survive in a competitive marketplace then at some point you will be forced to deal with the fact that you cannot treat all SE sites the same. Better to start sooner than later in configuring the software to smoothly deal with such localization demands. It's not rocket science and it need not "immensely slow down" anything if implemented correctly.

Comment: @Grace By the way, worth emphasis is the fact that already math.SE has some site specific localizations, namely MathJax support, which is not available on all SE sites.

Comment: @Bill A lot of the sites have specific stuff that's only enabled on them if not a small subset of sites, and that's fine. I'm not opposed to being able to screen out sites from global features.

Comment: Shorter version of Bill's comment: "one size *doesn't* fit all..."

Answer (score 26):

While it is hard to form a strong opinion about this without knowing how many posts are affected, *a priori* this seems like a dubious feature to implement on math.SE, given the particular (and sometimes peculiar) way that punctuation is used in mathematics.

While I appreciate the desire to clean up badly typeset questions, my guess would be that there are few posts that are rendered *incomprehensible* by virtue of poor punctuation, whereas there is a real possibility of rendering a piece of mathematics incomprehensible by altering its puncutation (and Jonas has given a real, and illustrative, example of this possibility).

Is it possible to get more data on this issue?  What is a typical example of a badly typeset post that is being improved by this automated process? And how many such posts are there?

Comment: According to the linked meta.SO question, a little more than 130,000 questions were affected.

Comment: @Qiaochu Let's speak about Math.SE only here -- which makes it more like 2 errors in 15 (fifteen!) edits (according to Shog9). Doesn't look _too_ effective to me...

Comment: @Grigory: I was a bit off... (see my edit) - only looking at question / exclamation marks didn't reveal the vast majority of the modifications came from correcting more subtle problems.

Comment: @Shog9, Qiaochu Yes, I got carried away, sorry. (But the real point is, SO sooo huge so it really has some specific problems not relevant to Math.SE. In particular, the question whether automatic edits are effective should be discussed separately for SO and for other sites, I believe.)

Answer (score 17):

I think it's pretty clear that the "!?" and "..." changes should not have been automatically implemented on Math.SE.  The main issue I see going forward is that this would have been obvious to anyone who writes mathematics on a regular basis, just as the foolishness of getting rid of "+?" would be to a user of SO.  What we need is some way to notice that changes are going to have bad affects on particular sites before they're implemented.

Is there an easy way to figure out what changes are about to be implemented short of reading every entry on meta.SO?  Would more people from math.SE following certain tags help?  Should there be a place where new changes are held for a day for discussion?

Comment: Officially, the elected site moderators are intended to be the "go-betweens"; of course, nothing stops anyone else with the time and interest from watching Meta.SO. [feature-request] is a pretty good tag, as are [the recent feature changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) lists. We're also trying to get more of this stuff into the newsletters we send out to moderators, although deciding what's important and what's trivial can be a challenge.

Comment: Ah good, I hadn't known previously that there was a recent feature changes list.  On the other hand, if I'm not mistaken the feature we're discussing here is not on that list.

Comment: @Shog9 Is there any sort of comprehensive change log for the SE platform? Any way to know when new revs are rolled out?

Comment: @Bill: there's an internal one, but it's not exactly usable for this (or any other external) purpose. The MSO feeds / questions are an *attempt* to get something usable, but not always comprehensive.

Comment: @Noah: my understanding is that SE rolls out various small changes frequently enough that it would completely drag down the whole process for all new changes to be subject to discussion. The underlying philosophy is that it's easier to beg forgiveness than ask permission: that way we only end up having the discussions that people actually care enough to have (like we're doing right now).

Comment: "easier to beg forgiveness than to ask permission" - reminds me of the Emo Philips joke, http://quotedb.net/when-i-was-a-kid-i-used-to-pray-every-night-for-a-new-bicycle-then-i-realised-that-the-lord-doesn’t-work-that-way-so-i-stole-one-and-asked-him-to-forgive-me-–-emo-philips/

Comment: @Qia The point is not discussion of pending changes but, rather, keeping an eye out for (unintended) consequences of existing changes. The more information the community has the better feedback they can provide. For example, if I know that a recent rev rolled out major changes to the MathJax interface then that is a very valuable piece of information to know when troubleshooting the source of related problems.

Comment: @Bill: Noah's suggestion is very clearly for discussion of pending changes, and it is to Noah's suggestion that I was responding.

Comment: @Qia "The underlying philosophy is that it's easier to beg forgiveness than ask permission"
You do understand what the proper game-theoretic move for the other player is? Make begging for forgiveness costlier.

Answer (score 16):

Yeah, that's crap. I've made a small edit to side-step the problem (on this and the one other question with the same issue), but obviously it's something that we'll need to be watchful for. Fortunately, it's not *common* to end a title in this way.

As for the reason behind it, and whether the benefits outweigh the costs... [Here's some data](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/q/109040/). This site has only 15 questions (as of the last data-dump) that end with ??, ?!, or !? - two of which were serving a useful purpose, and the rest being the usual "I'm incredulous?!" or "extra questiony question???" nonsense.

You could easily clean these up manually...

On the larger sites, or sites that aren't good about cleaning up titles, this can grow into a problem over time, leaving the site looking quite messy.

**Edit:** I'd missed that this script was also cleaning up titles that end with a space and then a question mark. [That adds another 250+ questions to the list](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/q/109044/) - probably a bit more work to get through by hand. There were also [80 or so questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/q/109046/) ending in ellipses / repeating periods that would have been modified.

Math.SE may not be among the worst offenders as far as superfluous ending punctuation goes, but looks like it did get *some* benefit from the script in exchange for a few false positives.

Comment: This is a classic example of a "big city solution" being misapplied on a small site. Mathematicians have peculiar requirements on their punctuation, and "false positives" that completely break meaning are really bad. (Like the death penalty, eh?)

Comment: The ellipses list includes a number of "false positives."

Comment: @Scott: for sure. On a site this size, a few conscientious editors could have taken care of the whole bunch without any external assistance.

Comment: @Noah: good catch. I've edited them (well, the ones I noticed) to avoid the problem. Note that some of these should have stuck out like a fist full of sore thumbs as lousy titles *anyway*...

Comment: @Shog9, so why run this script here? My point was not that "big city solutions" are *unneeded* here, but that they are actively harmful.

Comment: @Scott: It was run *everywhere*. Bit sites, little sites. So far, the number of false positives isn't high. As for *why*? Because the poorly-punctuated titles look bad and set a bad example for new users. This is no less a problem on small sites than on large ones. Yes, doing this automatically is less than ideal; in a perfect world, real live knowledgeable humans would be taking care of this, and *this* is actually much more feasible on smaller sites (we're making [some effort to kick-start more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/))... but some always slip through the cracks.

Answer (score 12):

I really think that if this such a problem at SO, then there should be separate scripts run on SO messages only. What's next? Say, leetspeak becomes way too common in some computer related SE. Consequently the geniuses at helm decide to run a script that substitutes all 3s, 1s and 7s with 'e', 'l', 't'...

Comment: The day when somebody comes to post an m.SE question entirely in 1337 is going to be a most interesting day...

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, this is an incredibly small exception to the general idea that it's probably a good idea to get rid of multiple punctuation marks, and is very unlikely to be an issue for more than a handful of questions on math and a few other sites. I'm curious why you think making a few old questions slightly less comprehensible could potentially be more harmful than cleaning up 100,000 other questions.

Comment: Perhaps, because, automagically altering a user's carefully composed text is a *very bad idea*. It's quite scary that the SE platform is implementing more and more of such Big Brotherish policies as time passes. Are your true opinions stifled now that you are an SE employee?

Comment: @Bill: no. I wish people would stop saying that. The content you generate on SE was never intended to be exclusively yours - there's a reason other users can edit your content, and that reason is that SE is supposed to be a community-maintained resource for the long term. Automating part of that maintenance is just a matter of efficiency, and if the automation makes a few mistakes, so what? They are easily fixable.

Comment: @Bill: if working at SE has changed my opinions in any way, it's helped me think of the SE team as a group of human beings trying to build a strong network rather than as monsters under the bed who are out to get us. I'm not sure I would call this "stifling" so much as correcting for the cognitive bias of tribal thinking.

Comment: @Bill It seems pretty clear that the mechanism was not put in place to alter "carefully composed text", but rather sloppily thrown out garbage. It is clear that no automatic algorithm will be able to tell the one from the other in 100% of the cases. Which is why Jonas asked the question whether the benefits outweigh the cost. You think that the cost cannot be outweighed, but others may think differently. I think that this is a serious and honest discussion that is worth having. Ideally, one should form his opinion after knowing what the benefits and the costs are precisely, and not before.

Comment: @Alex B. Besides being a mathematician, I also have extensive experience in software engineering. My various critiques of the SE platform are based upon such. Many of the SE "features" are ill-conceived "hacks" or "kludges" as one would say in CS lingo. There are far too many subtleties involved in automatic text editing for such to be automated by machine. Such editing should only be done by humans - of which we have many here the last time I counted.

Comment: @Bill My point was that presenting your experience as concrete justification of your critique would be more valuable and would further the discussion more than comparisons with 1984 and insinuations that Qiaochu is not expressing his own opinion.

Comment: @Qia The issue has nothing to do with other *humans* editing content. Rather, it has to do with ill-conceived buggy *software hacks* that forcibly alter our texts. On such matters it is always better to pull in the reins sooner than later.

Comment: @Alex B. A question in not an insinuation. And the hyperbole *is* explicitly intended.

Comment: If there's one thing I love about visiting this site, it's the hyperbole. Some sites use it like salt - a little bit for seasoning. [No such cowardly restraint here](http://www.bad-candy.com/candies/saltidos/)!

Comment: @Shog9 In my case the hyperbole comes from having seen it all in decades of participation in sci.math. What occurs here is quite mild compared to what occurs in a free-for-all usenet newsgroup. I suspect some folks take it more seriously than it is intended due to the difference in cultures. But, alas, by now it is so subconscious that it's difficult to tone down while in the SE church.

Comment: @Shog9 That said, it is worth emphasis that because mathematics compresses so much information into its highly optimized language, the odds of altering its meaning by automatically changing a single character is much higher than in other fields. That's not to say it doesn't happen elsewhere, e.g. recall the famous joke about the *importance of the lowly comma:* this text message was sent from a wife to her husband: $$\rm\text{NOT GETTING ANY, BETTER COME HOME AT ONCE.}$$"

Comment: @Bill: oh, it's dangerous elsewhere; another recent modification was to warn authors against the use of "tags" (keywords stuffed into brackets) on the front of titles - this was proposed ages ago, but controversial because bracketed text could also be a subscript (in many SO questions). Of course, no one should be *starting* a title with a subscript, but... Ultimately, it's a trade-off between discouraging very common *misuse* at the potential expense of breaking rare *but correct* uses. The better solution by far is to simply fix it by hand before it gets out of control.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Thank you.  For the record, I am disturbed by Bill's first comment and its upvotes.  As for why I think it could potentially be more harmful, I think that Alex B put it well about knowing what the benefits and costs are before forming an opinion.  I also think it would be possible to implement the auto-corrections on SO (where most of those 100,000 instances occur) without implementing it on math.SE (where there is higher potential for error).  (My concern was also because of Grigory M's point that it is hard to see what is going on, but he has already made a new thread for that.)

Comment: Deletion of ellipsis leads to use of hyperbole. Are we going around in circles?

Comment: For the record: I upvoted Bill's first comment for the first sentence, but I certainly don't like the last two sentences...

Comment: For the record: I, too, upvoted Bill's first comment. In spite of the (cheap) shot (obviously made in jest, if you ask me) taken at Qiaochu, not because of it. I'm sure Bill shares the majority view that Qiaochu is doing a very fine job. But: Bad writing should be fixed by hard working school teachers, not a mindless robot working under the assumption that the author is uneducated.

Comment: @Jyrki: if you think that last sentence was "obviously made in jest," you haven't talked to Bill very much. If you think that it would be at all feasible to hire enough people to go through every question on the SE network to fix their writing... I don't even know what to say to that.

Comment: @Qiaochu: What I think Jyrki was getting at was not that users comb through the archives for fixing these; if a user with edit privileges happens to come across these, then s/he can fix them. Again, *only* when somebody conveniently comes across them. (though I suppose somebody will counter this with "we can't afford to have broken windows"...)

Comment: @J.M.: broken windows isn't exactly the right analogy. It just seems incredibly inefficient to me to make these small fixes in a non-automatic way. Either we don't reach a lot of questions or we do, but they all get bumped because ordinary users are editing them. It's just a huge amount of time and effort compared to a quick SQL command.

Comment: @Qiaochu: For the record. I appreciate your work for us very much. But I really don't see bad spelling/language/extra punctuation/smileys as a problem at all. It is not as if we should put a similar proofreading effort into our scribblings here as we might, when, say, writing a textbook, a dissertation or a scientific article. At least I won't. For some it comes naturally, and kudos to them. If the site owners later want to collect material with impeccable English only for some other use ... it's their problem.

Comment: @Jyrki The point of the last sentence in my first comment was to spur Qiaochu to be a bit more reflective on the more delicate nature of his role in the community now that he's an SE employee. When I read Qiaochu's answer the author was offscreen. I assumed it was written by Jeff Atwood. Of course I was quite surprised when I scrolled further to find the true author. Transitioning back and forth between academia and the corporate world is a difficult journey. It forces one to deal with many conflicting demands. For those beginning that journey it is important to be cognizant of the perils.

Comment: @Qia By the way, how did you make the very strange inference that criticizing poorly designed software equates to considering the designers to be  "monsters under the bed who are out to get us"? Did you find [The Three Stooges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Stooges) scary?

Comment: @Bill: in my experience here and on meta.MO, it seems to me that some of the more vocal criticism comes from a strong "us vs. them" mentality that I find unconstructive. I was calling out this attitude.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I have noticed that, too, and I appreciate you calling it out.

Comment: @Qia I don't see any "us vs. them". For example, in my case I relay both (constructive) criticism and praise, as the situation merits. For example, a couple days ago I [thanked](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/should-we-avoid-mathjax-if-it-is-not-necessary/2734#2734) Jeff and the SE team for the great MathJax support. The bug reports and critiques here are G-rated compared to most of what occurs in the software industry.

Comment: @Bill: It is hard for me to understand how speaking of "scary" trends toward "Big Brotherish" policies can be constructive here.  There is nothing sinister here.  Automatic edits were done to help clean up many sloppy posts.  However, there are potential downsides to this, at least on this site, due to "the particular (and sometimes peculiar) way that punctuation is used in mathematics," to quote Matt E.  Jeff Atwood and others who run these sites cannot please everyone at all times, but they are clearly invested in the success of the sites.

Comment: @Jonas As I emphasized above, and as should be abundantly clear by now, I call them as I see them - sometimes adding a little bit of hyperbole for emphasis, humor, etc. I think, perhaps, you may be reading into the hyperbole far more than what was intended.

Comment: @Bill: I do not presume to read your intentions, and I suppose my being disturbed says as much about me as anything.  Excessive hyperbole in the direction of comparing those with whom you have a disagreement with totalitarian thugs *is* humorous in a way, but in a way that makes it hard for some of us to take your point seriously.  Tastes differ.  Personally, I prefer Gerry Myerson's brand of humor.

Comment: To address Qiaochu's point: I'm here only for math.SE. I never see those 100000 posts. I only see the 2 out of 15. I'm barely aware of the existence of the other parts of the SE hierarchy, and until today I thought that math.SE is one of the biggest chunks around. Anyway, in math.SE editing done by the regulars will salvage any question worth saving. The others get closed or forgotten post haste. I honestly don't see a problem here.

Comment: @Jonas The conical wordplay between Gerry and I goes way back, e.g. see [this 2004 sci.math post](http://groups.google.com/groups?selm=y8zk6vkbnu7.fsf@nestle.csail.mit.edu). But don't say I didn't warn you!

Comment: @Jonas The hyperbole was not excessive. I *am* scared by some of what I've seen here lately. E.g. in a [recent thread](http://bit.ly/qxTv9k) it was proposed to eliminate all subjective words from titles. That's Big Brotherish to me. What's next, automatic deletion of all subjective words throughout the site? A mathematics site would be impotent if one could not speak of a *beautiful* proof, or a *difficult* conjecture solved by *surprisingly simple* method (using the appropriate punctuation!) Subjective matters *do* play a *huge* role in mathematics. Passion should be welcomed, not eliminated.

Comment: @Bill: "between Gerry and I"??? Where's the automated grammar-correcting software when you need it?

Comment: @Gerry: From Webster's dictionary of English usage: "Conclusion: you are probably safe retaining between you and I in your casual speech..." It cites uses by Shakespeare, Twain, etc. But grammar is the least of our worries with groaners like those...